Specific file inside "Program Files" directory has location reverted after reboot (but only sometimes)
I have Windows 11 Pro. I have an apache/php webserver setup that is installed to the Program Files directory.
Inside the PHP directory I have two folders that I created called conf and dist.
There is an xdebug.ini that enables my xdebug extension that I keep in the conf directory.
PHP is configured to check that conf directory for additional INI files upon loading (but not the dist folder). This is by design as when I want to turn off xdebug at the server level, I can move the xdebug.ini file to the dist folder, restart apache and then xdebug will not be loaded.
I have a shell script that I run via git bash called togglexdebug and when this command is run, it stops apache, then moves the xdebug.ini file either from dist to conf (reporting it has then been enabled) or from conf to dist (reporting that it has been disabled). The action taken output is issued upon restarting apache.
The script bit may be important as it might have something to do with it, not sure, just covering my bases. As I said, I generally keep xdebug enabled so the ini file is always in that conf folder.
The problem is that on very rare occasions, I'm talking like once every 1-2 months, after a reboot (and not after all reboots, literally at random, and I cannot reliable reproduce the behavior no matter how hard I try), the xdebug.ini file will magically be in the dist folder when I know for a fact the previous day it was in the conf folder that I had not personally move this file at all.
To make things even more freaky, I added a log to the toggledebug script to log each time it's ran and what it did so that I could rule out the script being run somehow from somewhere. I only ever use the script to move this file. No manual moving it, ever. The log file literally shows that I never have run the command and it resulted in disabling xdebug since I started checking this. Every entry was me running the script after this twilight zone scenario occurring.
Here are the entries since I started logging:
Wed, Feb 07, 2024  1:30:34 PM -- XDEBUG ENABLED!
Tue, Mar 19, 2024  1:53:05 PM -- XDEBUG ENABLED!
Thu, Apr 18, 2024  4:49:52 PM -- XDEBUG ENABLED!

I am sure the disabled log works as I have tested it. This confirms the script is not being run to disable xdebug, which means either:

Windows (or system process like defender) is "restoring" the location of that file under some circumstance that only occurs at some specific points in time (after updates maybe?).
I am sleepwalking into my office and manually moving the file just mess with "conscious me's head"

Does anyone have any clue as to what is doing this, and why, and more importantly how do I stop it from happening?
I tried to find any type of logs and search the event viewer but I wasn't able to find anything, unfortunately...

How did you install the server?  If MSI was used, something could be triggering a silent repair.

The apache server / php instance is installed via an installer from the "EasyPHP DevServer" package, so I suppose some sort of installer was used. Its an EXE I download and run, not a .msi though.

So MSI "repair" is a thing though? That's what I'm trying to figure out. I feel that is a very good guess and I will look into that!

Not that this should come up for anyone else, I'm updating this with the solution I figured out. It turns out this situation appears to be of my own doing. Based on Señor CMasMas's comment I started to move my INI scan directories outside of program files to see if this would help. I wen to update my shell script that toggles the location of the INI file when I discovered I have another shell script that also moves this file when I run the "composer" command because apparently way back when, composer would complain heavily if xdebug was enabled in PHP when you run it. So to fix that, I overrode the "composer" command line to first  move the ini file to the DIST folder, run the composer command, return the output, then restore the INI file.
My new hypothesis is that on occasion the composer command would not finish or something would glitch out and my script ending where the ini file is restored would never be run. This also bypassed my logging of the moving of the file.
It turns out composer has been long since updated to not have this issue with xdebug so I removed my shell script override, and expect to not have to deal with this anymore.
